# How to echo variables in vertical order

Tags: linux, bash

I need help in this echo command. I want it to echo variables in vertical order but this didn't work for me

```
A=$(initctl status worker1)
B=$(initctl status worker2)
var="$(echo -e "\n$A \n$B")"
```

Comment: it takes the status of workers of action hero

Comment: Going out on a limb, I'm guessing that you then use `$var` without quotes, when you should have used `"$var"`. https://shellcheck.net is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A="$(initctl status worker1)"
B="$(initctl status worker2)"
var="$(echo -e "$A\n$B")"
```

then you can print the vertically formatted output, e.g. using:

```
echo "$var"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not put that echo inside of the var. Maybe this can help?

```
var="${A}\n${B}"
echo -e $var
```